# Any popular and good Scala library for Apache Cassandra?

Tags: scala, cassandra, phantom-dsl

Actually I know good Java high level API and ORM for Apache Cassandra - Hector. 
But can't find any native good solution for Scala. Anybody know any actual project with good quality, activity and ORM support for SuperColumns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Phantom](https://github.com/websudosuk/phantom) is actively developed and very well designed Scala DSL built on top of Datastax client.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Scalandra](https://github.com/nodeta/scalandra/)  a wrapper for Cassandra's Thrift API.

Comment: Found it too. But the latest version updated in 2010. It looks like dead project now.

Answer (score 0):

Besides [scalandra](https://github.com/nodeta/scalandra/) there is also [cascal](https://github.com/shorrockin/cascal) and [scromium](https://github.com/cliffmoon/scromium)

Comment: Same as Scalandra. These not active projects too. Latest activity are dated 2010.